# jquery on click <a tag not working with my parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried few example but nothing works. But i got the alert so i really don't understand.
Why am I getting alert when my form doesn't send any data?
If I work with a input everything works fine.
I also tried to put my script in my js file but still the same result.

```
<form action="includes/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">  
    <li class='mainMenu menuDeroulant' id='btnGames'>
        Jeu <img class='arrow' src="Styles/Images/triangle.png" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class='mainMenu' id='btnReward'>Récompenses <img class='arrow' src="Styles/Images/triangle.png" alt=""></li>
    <input class='loginInfo' type="text" placeholder='Username' name="email">
        <input class='loginInfo' type="password" placeholder='Password' name="password" id="password">
    <li id='btnJouer' class='mainMenu'>JOUER</li>
    <li class='mainMenu' id='btnPlayer'>Player <img class='arrow' src="Styles/Images/triangle.png" alt=""></li>
    <li id='btnAdmin' class='mainMenu menuDeroulant'>Admin <img class='arrow' src="Styles/Images/triangle.png" alt=""></li>
    <li class="mainMenu loginInfo"><img src="Styles/Images/facebookBtn.png" alt=""></li>                    
    <li class='mainMenu loginInfo'><a id="myanchorid" href="#">Connexion</a></li>
    <li class='mainMenu loginInfo'>Inscription</li>
    <a href="indexEN.php"><li class='mainMenu'>EN</li></a>     
</form>

<script>
  $(function(){
    function yourfunction(event) {
      alert('some anchor clicked');
      formhash(this.form, this.form.password);
      return false;
    }
    $('#myanchorid').click(yourfunction);
    $('a.anchorclass').click(yourfunction);
    $('#anchorlist > a').click(yourfunction);
  });
</script>
```

my js file:

```
function formhash(form, password) {
// Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 

    var p = document.createElement("input");

    // Add the new element to our form. 
    form.appendChild(p);
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "hidden";
    p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

    // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
    password.value = "";

    // Finally submit the form. 
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: don't do password hashing on client side.. It is like use a plain text password without hashing anyone who intercepts this can simply resend the exact same thing, thus making any function like this equivalent to using the password directly.

Comment: The best way - use https, it save you from man-in-middle-attack !

Comment: ok what should i do for more security?

Comment: yes i'll use https but for now i test on local

Comment: so, u dont need that function for hash - https dont let anyone read password except ur client and ur server!

Comment: ok thanks good to know but i still want to know why my scripts isnt working
i'm going to use the same syntax for other link

Comment: The problem is `this` refers to the clicked element and not the `form`

Comment: @MartinDubois edit my ans, try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `function formhash(form, password)` is outside the scope of `$(function(){` block. So, the alert is being fired, but formhash is undefined.

Move your `formhash` block inside of the `$(function(){` block.

Next, what is being sent to the formhash function? Try this instead:

```
  function yourfunction(event) {
        alert('some anchor clicked');
        formhash($("form")[0], $("#password"));
        return false;
  }
```

Also, `hex_sha512` is undefined. Hope this all helps!!

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6bL6kj54/3/

Comment: TypeError: input is undefined

Comment: Works. Demo included. ^^

Comment: i receive all alert but the page never reload

Comment: Could you browse to http://jsfiddle.net/6bL6kj54/3/ and see if that is doing what you wish? (Sorry! I commented out the form.send() for debugging purposes. It works now. ^^)

Comment: when i click on the button all value username and passord should be empty

Comment: Wait, if the username is blank, then it wont be sent to the server. I made the password go blank. Do you want only the hashed password sent?

Comment: Thank you! I hope this is the answer you were looking for ^^